# Add custom field to Filebeat

Tags: logstash, kibana, filebeat

Hy,

I have a filebeat.yml file (installed on a DEV server, sending data to logstash and further to kibana) and I would like to show one extra field with the environment I am working with.
environment = "DEV"

But I didn´t find out, how I add such a filed in my filebeat configuration.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you check out the documentation? There are examples in the documentation, you can do [this way](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-general-options.html#libbeat-configuration-fields) or [this way](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/add-fields.html#add-fields).

Comment: Yes, I have tried this way... but it doesn´t work.. I don´t get shown the added fields

Comment: @Clies where does the added field doesn't get shown? Because in kKibana, if I remember right, new fields don't automaticaly show up.

Comment: Thank you very much .. I found out the issue, kibana made an automatically update and after that, nothing worked like it should :D ..